# How is install -c different from cp

Tags: linux, installation, bash, cp, sh

What is the difference between `install -c` and `cp`? Most installations tend to use `install -c`, but from the `man` page it doesn't sound like it does anything different than `cp` (except maybe the ability to also set permissions). When should I use `install -c` and when `cp`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One significant difference is that cp truncates the destination file and starts copying data from the source into the destination file.

install, on the other hand, removes the destination file first.

This is significant because if the destination file is already in use, bad things could happen to whomever is using that file in case you `cp` a new file on top of it. e.g. overwriting an executable that is running might fail. Truncating a data file that an existing process is busy reading/writing to could cause pretty weird behavior. If you just remove the destination file first, as install does, things continue much like normal - the removed file isn't actually removed until all processes close that file.

Comment: Good answer. But see also `cp --remove-destination` in GNU coreutils.

Comment: I'm a bit shocked that cp's default is to truncate instead of replace the destination file. Isn't that a dangerous default behavior in general?

Comment: Awesome -- thanks, @PeterEisentraut, I wasn't aware of that flag

Answer (score 11):

Technically, the difference between `install -c` and `cp` is that `install` sets the permissions of the target file to `rwxr-xr-x`.  `cp` preserves the permissions of the source file minus the umask.  These default behaviors are useful in different situations.  Obviously, with all the options that both `cp` and `install` offer nowadays, the functionalities have converged.

Nowadays, `install` is commonly used in makefiles, `cp` everywhere else.  This distinction is occasionally useful because some operating systems or installation systems allow you to hook into the `install` program to register the installed packages.  Modern package management systems make this kind of obsolete, but some people still use it.  Also, the possibility to set the target file permissions in the same go is very convenient.

Answer (score 5):

The `install` utility, at its base, is a fancy `cp`.  But as a tool specifically do installs it contains a few features that `cp` doesn't.  My `/usr/bin/install` from GNU coreutils not only copies, but also can change perms/ownership as arg flags (saving `chgrp`, `chown`, `chmod` invocations) an option to strip debug info (saving a `strip` invocation) and also some mojo for SELinux contexts.

It just provides convenience actions useful for software installs.  None are life changing, all are useful, and make your scripts cleaner.